.useNTreads() function from corrplot pakage error
Hello when i try to use this code
rld <- rlog(dds, blind=FALSE)

boxplot(assay(rld), pch=20, las=2)

corr <- corrplot(cor(assay(rld)), cl.lim = c(0.95,1), is.corr = F, tl.col = "black",
col = colorRampPalette(c("#0099FF","ivory","#FF0090"))(200))

The package retrieves this error
Error in .useNThreads() : could not find function ".useNThreads"

And i don't know how to fix it as i already used that package with the same code and got it functioning well.

Looks like it's from the WGCNA package. Did you run library(WGCNA) first?

corr <- corrplot(cor(assay(rld)), cl.lim = c(0.95,1), is.corr = F, tl.col = "black", looks like this you are getting the data from deseq2 output as i see this assay(rld) its better to save it as data frame and then run corrplot you don't need to use WGCNA package dependencies

I wasnt using WGCNA dependences, i have thata package installed but it wasnt load also i tryed to uninstall bot pakcages corrplot and WGCNA to fix the error ans it still doesnt work
